# Generate Access report from multiple queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

I have browsed a few answers on this topic but they all suggest using UNION queries and I'm pretty sure that's not the way to go in my case as the tables I'm trying to extract data from are fundamentally different. I'll try to explain to the best of my abilities.

I have three tables:

> - Customers
> - Appointments
> - Purchases

I wish for the user to be able to select a single customer and be presented with a report with the following information:

> - All the customer information (Name, email, address etc.)
> - All the appointments booked by the customer
> - All the purchases made by the customer

The problem arises when a customer does not have an appointmet or a purchase in the database as the single query I'm using at the moment does the following:

```
SELECT (info needed)
FROM (Customer INNER JOIN Purchase ON Customer.ID = Purchase.customerID)
INNER JOIN Appointment ON Customer.ID = Appointment.customerID;
```

If a customer does not have their customerID in the Purchase or Appointment table the resulting query will return an empty table since the JOIN won't be able to see any shared data between the tables.

I'm not sure what the best course of action would be and I hope someone here can shed some light on what the best practices are in this kind of situation, thanks in advance.

Suggested edit to add some sample data and desired results.

> Customers

```
ID   Name  email           address
 1   Bob   bob@gmail.com   70 bowman st.
 2   Tom   tom@gmail.com   44 shirley av.
 3   Mary  mary@gmail.com  4 goldfield rd.
```

> Purchases

```
customerID itemID price
1          23     100
1          24     150
3          34     85
```

> Appointments

```
customerID date
1          2/10
2          3/10
3          3/10
```

Now if I query with customerID = 2 I want the following info

> Customer Info

```
name   email          address
Tom    tom@gmail.com  44 shirley av.
```

> Purchases

```
empty
```

> Appointments

```
date
3/10
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left join instead of inner join. So that you will get customer details even if he has not made an appointment or purchase

```
SELECT (info needed)
  FROM Customer Left 
  JOIN Purchase 
    ON Customer.ID = Purchase.customerID
Left JOIN Appointment 
  ON Customer.ID = Appointment.customerID;
```

Comment: I am dumb, that is exactly what I needed to do, thanks for the swift reply.

Comment: None is dumb :-) Sometimes we forget.. Its nature

Comment: I'm going to ask this here as it doesn't warrant another thread, do you know of a way of splitting the report in two details sections? I know about grouping but I don't really have anything to group things on, the page is only for one customer and the two sections should be "all appointments" and "all purchases". Is the only way using subreports?

Comment: Split the query in to two queries. One with customer left join purchase.
 Another with customer left join Appointment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I think you misunderstood my question, I'm now asking about MS Access specifically. When creating a Report you have a "details" section that repeats for as many entries as your data provides, I am looking for a way to have 2 separate details sections, one repeating for each purchase, and one repeating for each appointment. I don't have an issue with extracting the data, but with presenting it in the report.

Comment: Ms access - It's pretty new to me. Sorry I couldn't help you

Comment: It's quite alright, I managed a sub-optimal fix but a fix nonetheless, thanks again for your time.